# Compiler options in Andriod.bp files

Tags: android, android-soong

everyone.
I'm trying to convert a makefile to a .bp file for Android Q and i'm facing some issues.

1) I'm not sure how to define a release version.
Previosly in makefile i would just write something along the lines of:

```
MY_RELEASE_VERSION := $(shell cd $(LOCAL_PATH); git describe --always
--dirty) DSW_VERSION= \"$(MY_RELEASE_VERSION)\"
```

Which would be defined as a string like for example:  DSW_VERSION="project_specific_3_0"

Now i am able to use a cppflag in .bp with the DSW_VERSION , but i found no way to make the value of it to be taken like in the makefile.
Something like:

```
MY_RELEASE_VERSION = ["__builtin_func:shell cd <'LOCAL_PATH' unset>; git describe --always --dirty"]
CPPFLAGS = [
 "DSW_VERSION = "\"MY_RELEASE_VERSION"\",
]
```

Does not work.

Secondly i'm facing issues in defining a config variant, which in turn would devine a variable from the source code.
Something like this in .mk files:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS +=$(TARGET_CONFIG)
```

With a ifdefine in the code that looks like this:

```
#if defined (TARGET_ONE)
    static const VAR   = 1;
#elif defined (TARGET_TWO)
    static const VAR     = 2;
```

i tried in .bp appendind to the cppflags, something like :
`cppflags: MY_CPPFLAGS + TARGET_CONFIG`,
 where MY_CPPFLAGS is a variable defined with all the flags needed and it doesn't work

Anyone can help me with those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `genrule` to generate code at build time (e.g. a header file containing the repository version). Check out the [Wayland Android.bp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wayland/+/refs/heads/pie-release/Android.bp#39) as an example on how a `genrule` looks like.

To answer your second question: You can use `cflags` to add defines:

```
<some-module> {
    [...]
    cflags: ["-DTARGET_CONFIG"],
}
```